# Form element within two separate grid columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two forms on a page. Both I would like in the left column in a two-column layout, but the second form has input fields stretching onto the second column.

I could of course create two separate "rows". However, the design calls for the top position of the columns to be at the same height, like columns in a two-column layout typically display.

I don't believe this is necessarily related to Bootstrap because this might be solved with other methods, but I was wondering if Bootstrap had a quick solution for this

This following approach is obviously incorrect syntax and moves the form element in and out of flow, but this is basically what I'd like to accomplish:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="form1">
      </form>
      ...
      <form id="form2">
      <!-- ... #form2 inputs ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- ... #form2 inputs cont'd ... -->

      </form> <!-- end of #form2 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can already separate the forms on two separate rows, but of course, the right column is lower than the left column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="form1">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of row -->

  <div class="row">
    <form id="form2">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- ... #form2 inputs ... -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- ... #form2 inputs cont'd ... -->
      </div>
    </form> <!-- // end of #form2 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any trick to "collapsing" the space above the right column if this is how the html should be structured, or is there a Bootstrap approach that I'm missing? Open to non-bootstrap methods if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using just one form element to wrap the whole lot, and then separating the two forms using their name attributes? For example:

```
value="form1[field_name]"
value="form2[field_name]"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a popular eCommerce plugin for a popular CMS that makes a lot of layout assumptions within its checkout page. I didn't want to mention that in the initial post because a) it was more related to HTML structure, and b) I simply didn't want the can of worms to be opened. But in answer to your question, that's likely how I would've done it if doing it from scratch.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I can understand why you would want to avoid mentioning it.